# plugin: 'init' hook, check if we're not in admin

Tags: wp-admin, hooks, frontpage, init, front-end

I've tried this inside of my plugin ('init' hook) but it doesn't work:

```
if(is_front_page() || is_singular() || is_archive()) { ... }
```

How could I check it using init hook?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`init` is too early for [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to work. It marks when core finished loading, but no environment is set up yet.

For admin area only you can hook into `admin_init`.

For conditionals on front end earliest hook you can reliable use is `template_redirect`.

Comment: Is template_redirect executed before headers are send? Thanks.

Comment: @thom yes, there should be no output before it.

Comment: Rarst, thanks so much for this.  You solved my problem by giving info on the template_redirect hook.  now the is_page('page name') method works perfectly!